# Extract text before last left paretheses appearing before first colon

Tags: regex

I have stings containing colons and many pairs of parentheses.Followings are a few examples:

```
hello(string1)(string2):string3:string4
foo(string1):string2
foo(string1)(string2):(string3)
```

I want all the content of strings before the left parentheses appearing just before the first colon. The output for above mentioned string examples must look like:

```
hello(string1)
foo
foo(string1)
```

I used `^.*?(?=:)` to get all the content appearing before first colon (`:`). Now I need to get all the contents before the last left parentheses `(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `^.*?(?=\([^\)]+\):)`

Note that this *requires* the `:` to exist (at least at the end).  If there is no colon there is no `(.):` there won't be a match.

http://rubular.com/r/0n5Ch2bDFZ

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex:

```
^.*(?=\(.*\):)
```

it matches any characters that are followed by `\(.*\):`, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

Here is the look-ahead that finds the brackets followed by the colon: `(?=\([^)]*\):)`